# converting JSON to NSDictionary or NSArray - iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6

I have this bit of code:

```
[self.vManager playersNearLocation:userLocation
                             block:^(NSSet *players, NSError *error)
    {
        if(players && [players count])
        {
            NSLog(@"Success in getting players");
            /* TO DO
              Convert JSON to Objective C object here
            */   
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Failed to get players");
        }
    }];
```

I am receiving JSON from the server, how do I convert it to a Dictionary or array object. I dont want to use any external libraries, is there a native way?

Thanks

Comment: refer this link:-http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: do you have your json data in some doc file or directly fetching from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `NSJSONSerialization` and method

```
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy to parse json if you have SBJSON library :[SBJSON](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)

Include this library in your project .Import json.h and you can parse json as follow

```
   SBJSON *parser=[[SBJSON alloc]init];

NSDictionary * dictionary = [parser objectWithString:responseString];
```

Comment: Take note of *I dont want to use any external libraries, is there a native way?* ;-)